# ActiveMQ Deployment model

Tags: deployment, activemq-classic

I have gone through (not fully) ActiveMQ and tried to figure out the deployment model for my application. 
I am bit confused on that. 
I want to make the system High Availability and decided to use the following. Please correct me if anything is wrong or disadvantage of the model.

**Deployment Modle**:

1. Will deploy Brokers in M1 and M2 respectivley.
2. Use Hardware load balancer (Either F5 or Zeus) to connect either one of the broker (M1 or M2) based on the load.
3. Want to publish a message using Load balancer URL.

I have gone through network of brokers and we need to mintain some topology. I fell which makes the system more complicated if system grows horizontally. So it is better to have one load balancer to distribute the load.

*Questions*

1. Is this above model will send message to any one of the Broker?
2. Consumer Will be deployed in Tomcat (Think i need to use embeded brokers to configure either M1 or M2). Is it possible to use Load balancer URL instaed of M1 or M2?
3. Is it possible to have single Web Console Admin to monitor both M1 and M2.
4. Do we have any performance issue using Spring's feature to consume message.

Sorry to shoot out so many questions. Please help me to correct the deployment model.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to get some load balancing with some activemq servers is having a :  [network of brokers](http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html) and your consumers/producers (in your webapps) should use some [failover](http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html)

So if a producer p1 send a message on a queue on broker 1, the consumer c1 can read the message on broker 2.

[Edit] I have never tried to add some hardware balancer instead of the activemq protocole failover. It should work : just try it and tell us.

3- I do not think it is possible to have only one Web Console to monitor both of your brokers.

4- As far as I am concerned I do not have any performance issue with my Spring configuration.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of questions there.

The first thing is to do is start simple. If your application's load is being handled with just one broker, consider setting up high availability through a [master-slave setup](http://activemq.apache.org/masterslave.html). For this **you do not need a load balancer** - the ActiveMQ client library has a [failover mechanism](http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html) where you can define the URLs to a set of brokers that the client should attempt to connect to.

If you are looking at setting up an infrastructure where one broker will not be able to deal with the message load (you can test the maximum throughput of your broker using the [performance module](http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-performance-module-users-manual.html)), I would advise you to read up on [how networks of brokers work](http://www.jakubkorab.net/2011/11/understanding-activemq-broker-networks.html). If you do go down this path, you really need to understand ActiveMQ.

On monitoring, a web console can only show you the internals of a single broker. To get insight around what is going on around a set of brokers you will need a monitoring tool such as [FuseHQ](http://fusesource.com/products/fuse-hq/)/Hyperic that is able to aggregate JMX information from a number of boxes.

Performance with Spring is not a problem as long as you [configure it correctly](http://activemq.apache.org/spring-support.html) (see the section on `PooledConnectionFactory`).

I see that you are a new user, so if this answers your question, please tick it.